# Using a inductive sensor underwater

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor, inductive

I want to measure the speed of a gear underwater (max 10 meters or 33 feet).
The gear will be made out of stainless steal so I plan to mount a small piece of iron on top of it that will be reconcilable by the sensor. Because normally stainless steel has a value of 0.6 times steel I think it will work. I'm going to make the sensor inside a resin to make it watertight but will this work or am I forgetting something? [This is the sensor I intend to use.](http://nl.farnell.com/multicomp/mcpin-t30l-001/sensor-m30-npn-shielded-no/dp/2218047) [image: schematic overview]

Comment: I don't understand why you think the sensor won't detect stainless steel. Stainless is at least 75% Ferrous metal, so the sensor should detect it without any problems.

Comment: Because the stainless steel gear will be placed outside of the detecting range of the sensor and the iron add-on inside the detecting range.

Comment: Not much info on that sensor, does it work in air on your bench?  (Low speed motor?)

Comment: I don't have the sensor yet. [E2A-M18KN16-WP-C1](http://nl.farnell.com/omron-industrial-automation/e2a-m18kn16-wp-c1-2m/inductive-proximity-sensor-16mm/dp/2667230) maybe this is a better one

Comment: NPN-NO none of these type will work. You need an analog Hall sensor , amplifier and signal gain bandwidth conditioner with small hysteresis

Comment: Automotive crank sensors (just a magnet and a coil) are probably all you need; putting complex electronics underwater may be overkill.   Anything magnetic (including ferrite ceramics) should be sensed as it moves by.

Comment: @Dylan: You want to mesure **speed** but it is not clear at all what is the direction of movement and what does "max 10 meters or 33 feet" mean in this context? You say "stainless steel has a value of 0.6 times steel". What *value* are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

If the gear is rotating very quickly then it is possible that the sensor will not respond fast enough, those sensors are optimised for stability of detection rather than speed so you may have to test it first but it should be able to work underwater and will likely be just fine.

I would recommend a hall sensor though, that is what is typically used for this application. You can either mount a magnet on the gear or use a slotted or vane type sensor which can be used in a similar way to a photo-interrupter (but would be resistant to stuff that might build up and block light).

Answer (score 0):

It wont work because the sensor you chose needs a strong difference in iron size at max distance to give a digital logic decision.  Other methods can be used but need your explicit geometric limits and will need to be high gain analog  to be sensitive to gear tooth at a distance greater than tooth or iron slug.

How small can you make the gap to sensor?  few mm?

Comment: It can be as close as a millimeter if there is no misalignment. But I don't know how other ways will work.

Comment: I'm not really into the world of sensors but i thought this is one of the few sensors you can fully enclose without causing interference. can you maybe help me with an other type of sensor that would work?